# Issue connecting DocuSign admin to Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, docusignapi, dynamics-crm-365

I'm trying to setup integration of Docusign Admin with Microsoft Dynamics 365 portal. When I enter the docusign credentials and try to connect, it throws an error.

**Step 1**

[image: Login to Docusign in Dynamics 365]

**Step 2**

[image]

The following error occurs when I hit the connect button:

[image: Error]

I tried reinstalling the DocuSign in the Dynamics 365 environment, clearing all browser cache data also.

Can I have a fix for this?

Comment: Like it says: contact Docusign support..

Comment: The support people said to post this.@ArunVinoth

Comment: #docusign support